# Is there guarantee that my subList and Iterator/ListIterator see non-structural changes to original List?

Tags: java, list

If I obtain a `subList` from a `List` (or obtain an `Iterator` or `ListIterator` from a `List`) and after that do a non-structural modification (`set(index, E)`) - I am guaranteed to get no ConcurrentModificationException. But **is there guarantee that** my subList and **Iterator/ListIterator see those changes?**

Experimentally, when I make changes in the same thread (main()), subList and Iterator/ListIterator see those changes. But if I make changes from other threads? My guess - seeing chages guaranteed if made from synchronized method/block in another thread and not guaranteed otherwise (from non-synchronized code in other thread)

For Map collection views API is clear - if I obtain a collection view and then change original map (even replace) then collection view may or may not represent those changes, and no exception is thrown.

P.S. For subList - seeing non-structtural changes is guaranteed. It follows from [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in
>   the returned list are reflected in this list, ***and vice-versa***.

But API has no answer for Iterator and ListIterator.

Comment: Calling `set`, or modifying the `List` in any way, then interacting with an `Iterator` or `ListIterator` you created before the modification is an **error** - it will result in `ConcurrentModificationException`. The gurantee is true for a `subList` - as described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

Comment: "_But if I make changes from other threads_", again, from the documentation (for `ArrayList` for example) "_Note that this implementation is not synchronized_". Therefore **any** interaction across threads is UB. No idea where you get the documentation for a `Map` from, but it doesn't align with any documentation I have read...